# External contour of coplex figure within many circles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure which consists within three circles which overlap each other. But in result I would like to see only external contour of this figure and dont to see internal lines like on picture below. Is this possible with Circle module in matplotlib or needed other approach?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, patches
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
circle1 = patches.Circle((0.2, 0.2), radius=0.5, color='green', fill=None)
circle2 = patches.Circle((0.8, 0.6), radius=0.8, color='red', fill=None)
circle3 = patches.Circle((0.0, 0.8), radius=0.3, color='blue', fill=None)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.add_patch(circle2)
ax.add_patch(circle3)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Overlaped circles
[image]
External contour only
[image]

Comment: Maybe with the [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/shapely/) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're tempted to use [shapely](/questions/tagged/shapely), you can get the [`intersection`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.LineString.html#shapely.LineString.intersection) between your circles and their [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.unary_union.html)/[`boundary`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html#shapely.Polygon.boundary) :

```
bnd = unary_union(circles).boundary
ext = bnd.intersection(circles)

for mls, c in zip(ext, [*"gbr"]):
    for line in mls.geoms:
        plt.plot(*line.xy, color=c)

plt.gca().set_aspect("equal", adjustable="box")
```

A variant (*in one shot*) using [Set operations with overlay](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html#set-operations-with-overlay) from [geopandas](/questions/tagged/geopandas) :

```
(
    (gdf := gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=circles))
    .dissolve().boundary.to_frame()
    .overlay(gdf, how="intersection")
    .plot(colors=[*"grb"])
)
```

Output :

[image]

Used input (`circles`) :

```
from shapely import Point, unary_union
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

circles = [
    Point(0.2, 0.2).buffer(0.5),
    Point(0.8, 0.6).buffer(0.8),
    Point(0.0, 0.8).buffer(0.3),
]
```